# Отправка текста при нажатии на ENTER

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть текстовое поле, даже не textarea, а просто input, кнопки нету и не должно быть (так задумано). Мне нужно, чтобы когда нажимаешь на ENTER в текстовом поле, он выполнял ajax функцию.

```
<input placeholder='Введите сообщение...' id='txtmess'>

function gomess() { //Отправить сообщение
      var id = $("#idus").text();
      var txtmess = $("#txtmess").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/obr/mess.php',
          data: 'idus='+ id +'&txt='+ txtmess,
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          },
          error: function(xhr, str){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Находил такую функцию **onkeydown**, но как ей воспользоваться не знаю...
Подскажите какие-нибудь функции или желательно скрипт для примера.

Comment: А что мешает посмотреть пример в документации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('#txtmess').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if('key' in e){
      if(e.key.toLowerCase() !== 'enter') // Если свойство KeyboardEvent.key не равно enter - выходим
        return;
    }else{
      if(e.keyCode !== 13) // Более грубое, но более поддерживаемое свойство, 13 - enter
        return;
    }
    
    // Иначе убираем поведение браузера и делаем свои делишки
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('AJAX', this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input placeholder='Введите сообщение...' id='txtmess'>
```

Comment: obrphp.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: @СашаОсипов, видимо юзаете браузер без поддержки свойства `key`. Переписал пример под старые браузеры. Хотя лучше использовать `Babel` и писать нормальный код.

Comment: ну не знаю, браузер вроде не старый... yandex.brower последняя версия

Comment: А вот на моем раз работает, на других то будет?

Comment: Во всех других - конечно нет, в большинстве - скорее всего да.

Comment: А есть возможность сделать так, чтобы во всех браузерах?

Comment: Кроссбраузерность - вещь весьма непростая. 100% добиться нельзя, но вот чтобы пара-тройка последних браузеров поддерживалась - можно. Используйте транспайлер типа `Babel` - он компилирует новый код в старый вид, поддерживаемый старьём. К нему вроде есть плагины, которые даже хаки для `IE` добавляют (не всегда без автора решишь, но всё же...). Т. е. пишете современно и красиво, просто скармливаете его `Babel` и на выходе каша поддерживаемого кода.

Answer (score 0):

Привяжи выполнение функции к кнопке, например:

```
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            alert("Вы нажали Enter!");
        }
        // Отменяем действие браузера
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Дело в том, что кнопки не должно быть для стиля... Под hidden делать не желательно... Лишние строки.

Comment: @СашаОсипов, какая связь с кнопкой и ответом?

Comment: "Привяжи выполнение функции к **кнопке**"

Comment: я имел ввиду enter